# Alarm isn't executed on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I have an android app where I try to set an alarm. My code inside activity:

```
fun setAlarm() {
    alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(this, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    alarmManager!!.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, /*calculateAlarmTime()*/1, pendingIntent)

    Timber.i("setAlarm executed")
}
```

I set this alarm, calling setAlarm method. This is my NotificationReceiver class:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Timber.i("onReceive called");
    }
}
```

Why I have only "setAlarm executed" in logcat, and not "onReceive called"? I set alarm to 1 millisecond and it should trigger immeditately. Why nothing happens?

Comment: Use `setExact` instead of `set`. Read the documentation for both of these functions to see why and what the different behavior is.

Comment: I think it should fire immediately since it's being set at 1ms into 1970, i.e. very much in the past - have you registered your broadcast receiver in the manifest? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second parameter is wrong.  It isn't how long from now you want the alarm to occur, it's the Unix timestamp of when you want it to occur.  So 1 would have happened back in 1970.  You would need to, at minimum, go System.currentTimeMillis()+1.  Although that may well cause race conditions, I wouldn't count on an alarm being set for less than a second in the future working.

Comment: I had two mistakes. 1st - that u said, and as well I forgot to add receiver to manifest

Comment: **Adding the receiver to the manifest** was what I was missing, thank you @MaxSiomin!

Answer (score 0):

You set the AlarmManager with RTC_WAKEUP, so you should supply the exact date and time. Instead you set the time to 1 ms, which is interpreted as 1ms after 1-1-1970, 00h00m00s.
If you want to use an relative time from setting the alarmManager you should get the current RTC time, add a few seconds and set the alarmManager with that time. As this method is inexact, allow a few seconds leeway.
[See here for description RTC_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP)